# Using jQuery to get multiple elements by index

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way to use jQuery to get multiple elements by index -- something like [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), but where you can pass in an array instead of a single index?  Something like this:

```
var arrIndexes = [0, 4, 5];
var stuff = $("#datatable tbody tr").eq(arrIndexes).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Comment: How about just using a for loop? You cannot expect jquery to have every utility method known to man.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just use the first argument in filter (index) and look it up with indexOf

```
var arrIndexes = [0, 4, 5];
$("#datatable tbody tr").filter(function(index) {
    return arrIndexes.indexOf(index) > -1;
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ivexut/1/

you may need to add the function indexOf if you are in need of older browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for... I plugged it into my code and it worked like a charm.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use filter function of jquery to apply custom filter on the collection of objects returned by selector, You can read more about filter **[here](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/QLwpP/)**

```
$("#datatable tbody tr").filter(function(){
   if(arrIndexes.indexOf($(this).index()) != -1)
       return $(this);
}).css('background-color', 'red');
```